# Clickhouse: Difference in row results between 2 versions

Tags: clickhouse

In version **19.13.3.26** the following query returns 1 row:

```
select   -1 as brandidTotal, toDecimal64(Sum(CostpriceSEK),2) as costprice
  from mytable
  where Stylenumber = 'a row which does not exist'  
  group by brandidTotal
```

But in version **22.2.2.1** it returns an empty result (which i can understand, since where does not find any rows)

It seems like the aggregate function SUM has changed behaviour. (if second column is removed, both returns an empty set)

Is it possible to make version 22X handle it like 19x does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
  --empty_result_for_aggregation_by_constant_keys_on_empty_set 
            Return empty result when aggregating by constant keys on empty set.


select -1 x, count() from (select 1 yyy where 0) group by x;

0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.002 sec.


set empty_result_for_aggregation_by_constant_keys_on_empty_set=0;

select -1 x, count() from (select 1 yyy where 0) group by x;

┌──x─┬─count()─┐
│ -1 │       0 │
└────┴─────────┘
```

to enable it by default for all

```xml
cat /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/const_aggr_emp.xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<yandex>
    <profiles>
        <default>
            <empty_result_for_aggregation_by_constant_keys_on_empty_set>0</empty_result_for_aggregation_by_constant_keys_on_empty_set>
        </default>
    </profiles>
</yandex>
```

Comment: I can see that the setting you are referring to is new in version 22.X (not present in 19.X). So i guees the split the empty result setting into 2 in the newer version.

Comment: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/27932